Document AI - Processor location issue
I'm using a Mac and I have created a simple Document AI processor on the Google Cloud Platform (PDF splitter). This processor was trained, tested and deployed.
I'm now desperately trying to make use of this processor from Visual Studio Code (python 3.12.0) by sending it some pdf for processing. However, I keep getting the same error messages (including: "Invalid location: 'eu' must match the server deployment 'us'"). I have obviously checked the processor location multiple times, and there is no mistake here, so this doesn't seem to be the actual root problem.
It seems that despite my trials, the code is not able to connect to Document AI properly. I've tried my python code locally on Visual Studio code as well as on Google Colab, but unsuccessfully so far.
To simplify my issue, I'm now only trying to retrieve the list of processors from my Project, just to see if I can successfully authenticate and access Document AI. Here is what I have done in details:

Document AI: PDF splitter creation, training, testing and deployment
Service account creation (Document AI, Cloud storage permissions); Credential key downloaded and JSON saved locally in the same folder as the "main.py" script
In my terminal, installation of Document AI and Google Cloud SDK (might be an issue with initialisation of the Google Cloud SDK ?)
Run the following python code in Visual Studio Code:


Blockquote

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai

def list_document_ai_processors(project_id: str, location: str, service_account_file: str):
# Create the credentials object from the service account file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file)

# Create a Document AI client
client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

# Define the parent resource (location)
parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

# List processors
processors = client.list_processors(parent=parent)

# Print the list of processors
for processor in processors:
    print(f"Processor name: {processor.name}")
    print(f"Processor type: {processor.type_}")
    print(f"Display name: {processor.display_name}")
    print(f"State: {processor.state}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":

# Set your project ID, location, and path to the service account key file
project_id = "abmtest-429810"
location = "eu"
service_account_file = "/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/DocAI/credentials.json"

# List Document AI processors
list_document_ai_processors(project_id, location, service_account_file)

Now, this code keeps returning the same errors, which I haven't yet been able to fix:

Blockquote

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/DocAI/main.py", line 32, in <module>
list_document_ai_processors(project_id, location, service_account_file)
 File "/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/DocAI/main.py", line 16, in list_document_ai_processors
  processors = client.list_processors(parent=parent)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/Users/XXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/documentai_v1/services/document_processor_service/client.py", line 1493, in list_processors
response = rpc(
           ^^^^
 File "/Users/XXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/Users/XXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument. 
[field_violations {
  field: "parent"
  description: "Invalid location: \'eu\' must match the server deployment \'us\'"
}
]

Any help understanding the issue and potential fix would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Update: I finally found a similar post from 2021 that was properly answered. It now works for me with a processor based in the EU. Even the Document AI documentation was corrected in 2022 (my bad).

Did you try testing both processors for location 'eu' and 'us'? For me switching to a 'us' processor fixed the problem.
